# heroku - Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, following Hartl tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Running `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I get this error: `Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key`.

I made the correction recommended in SO question 25596504, specifically changing the file `carrier_wave.rb` to `carrierwave.rb` with no luck. I am following the Hartl tutorial page 688 which specifies adding them as `$heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY=<access key>`  I replaced the '' with quoted and unquoted versions of the actual key.  The keys show when I run heroku config, e.g., `S3_ACCESS_KEY:`  

The application was working before I began working on this section (11.4) of the tutorial re uploading images.  I, incidentally, know about the Figaro gem; however, I'd like to try following the tutorial's approach.  What am I missing?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your carrierwave.rb initializer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go on Heroku, on your application, go to settings, hit Reveal Config Vars.

Click on on Edit on the right side and enter your secrets there:

```
S3_BUCKET: name of your bucket goes here
S3_ACCESS_KEY: xxxxx
S3_SECRET_KEY: xxxx
```

On config/initializers/carrierwave.rb or wherever you're entering your secrets should have:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp') # adding these...
  config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave' # ...two lines

  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :s3_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],                        # required
    :s3_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],                     # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    :host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    :endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_Bucket']                             # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Comment: Should I replace 'AWS_KEY', 'AWS_SECRET', and 'AWS_BUCKET' with the actual values or leave as is?  Thanks.

Comment: you should leave it as is, never commit your secrets on github... then set them on Heroku config vars

Comment: That resolved it for me.  Please update your answer - so that it corresponds to Hartl's terminology for the benefit of others in the future - and I'll accept it.  It should be S3_ACCESS_KEY, S3_SECRET_KEY, and S3_Bucket.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 12):

Here is a tutorial I made after much work getting AWS to work with Heroku as described in Chapter 11 of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. I hope it helps:

Getting the Rails Tutorial Sample App to work between Heroku and AWS was a huge pain in the ass. But I did it. If you found this tutorial, that means you're probably encountering an error you can't get past. That's fine. I had a few of them.

The first thing you need to do is go back over the code that Hartl provided. Make sure you typed it (or copy/pasted it) in exactly as shown. Out of all the code in this section, there is only one small addition you might need to make. **The "region" environment variable.** This is needed if you create a bucket that is not in the default US area. More on this later. Here is the code for `/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb`:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      # Configuration for Amazon S3
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region                => ENV['S3_REGION']
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

That line `:region => ENV['S3_REGION']` is a problem for a lot of people. As you continue this tutorial you will learn what it's for.

You should be using that block of code exactly as shown. **Do NOT put your actual keys in there.** We'll send them to Heroku separately.

Now let's move on to your AWS account and security.

1. First of all, **create your AWS account.** For the most part, it is like signing up for any web site. Make a nice long password and store it someplace secure, like an encrypted password manager. When you make your account, you will be given your first set of AWS keys. You will not be using those in this tutorial, but you might need them at some point in the future so save those somewhere safe as well.
2. **Go to the S3 section and make a bucket.** It has to have a unique
   name, so I usually just put the date on the end and that does it. For example, you might name it "my-sample-app-bucket-20160126". Once you
   have created your bucket, click on the name, then click on Properties.
   **It's important for you to know what "Region" your bucket is in.** Find it,
   and make a note of it. You'll use it later.
3. Your main account probably has full permissions to everything, so let's not use that for transmitting random data between two web services. This could cost you a lot of money if it got out. We'll make a limited user instead. **Make a new User in the IAM section.** I named it "fog", because that's the cloud service software that handles the sending and receiving. When you create it, you will have the option of displaying and/or downoading the keys associated with the new user. It's important you keep this in a safe
   and secure place. It does NOT go into your code, because that will probably
   end up in a repository where other people can see it. Also, don't give this
   new user a password, since it will not be logging into the AWS dashboard.
4. Make a new Group. I called mine "s3railsbucket". This is where the
   permissions will be assigned. Add "fog" to this group.
5. Go to the Policies section. Click "Create Policy" then select "Create Your
   Own Policy". Give it a name that starts with "Allow" so it will show up near
   the top of the list of policies. It's a huge list. Here's what I did:

**Policy Name:** AllowFullAccessToMySampleAppBucket20160126
**Description:** Allows remote write/delete access to S3 bucket named
my-sample-app-bucket-20160126.
**Policy Document:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-sample-app-bucket-20160126",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-sample-app-bucket-20160126/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

6. Go back to the Group section, select the group you made, then add
   your new policy to the group.

That's it for AWS configuration. I didn't need to make a policy to allow
"fog" to list the contents of the bucket, even though most tutorials I tried
said that was necessary. I think it's only necessary when you want a user
that can log in through the dashboard.

Now for the Heroku configuration. This stuff gets entered in at your
command prompt, just like 'heroku run rake db:migrate' and such. This is
where you enter the *actual* Access Key and Secret Key you got from the "fog" user you created earlier.

```
$ heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY=THERANDOMKEYYOUGOT  
$ heroku config:set S3_SECRET_KEY=an0tHeRstRing0frAnDomjUnK  
$ heroku config:set S3_REGION=us-west-2  
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=my-sample-app-bucket-20160126
```

Look again at that last one. Remember when you looked at the Properties of
your S3 bucket? This is where you enter the code associated with your
region. If your bucket is not in Oregon, you will have to change `us-west-2` to your actual region code. This link worked when this tutorial was written:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

If that doesn't work, Google "AWS S3 region codes".

After doing all this and double-checking for mistakes in the code, I got
Heroku to work with AWS for storage of pictures!

Comment: Nice update!  You should share it with Michael Hartl in order to help improve his book.

Comment: Spent 5 hours and finally performed steps, you suggested. Everything works now!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome, thank you soooo much for this post! this should be the right answer!

Comment: @Max I followed everything you said but still getting this error : bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: I figured it out, I had to remove <> inside which I was putting my Access_key.

Answer (score 3):

I think this error occurred because the var name does not match.

In carrierwave.rb, you should replace :s3_access_key_id and :s3_secret_access_key with the prefix "aws".

```
    if Rails.env.production?
        CarrierWave.configure do |config|
        config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
        config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave'

        config.fog_credentials = {
          # Configuration for Amazon S3
          :provider               => 'AWS',                        # change var's name
          :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],         # change var's name
          :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRETE_KEY']
        }
        config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
      end
    end
```

And it can be deployed.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, running `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development` fixed this for me.
[and env vars don't need to be named `S3_ACCESS_KEY` etc, I used `aws.access_key_id`]

Comment: so after trying all the other answers, this is what worked for me. Cheers! Now does anyone have a clue why?!

Answer (score 0):

Running `rake assets:precompile` without any RAILS_ENV was the only way I could get it to precompile.