# How to find users, keys to see the pictures on production and how to ban some users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I could see the pictures in production and  I've completed  Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Harti.

How to ban some users?

Should I store banned users in a new database table and then check it every time someone tried to register? 
How to implement that? Maybe there is an another more simple and efficient  approach and implementation to bun some users?
Would you please collaborate?
thanks.

Comment: It is pointing to undefined method but this method is defined,,, so maybe definition is not the correct one.

Comment: It seems that you edited your question and changed it into an entirely different question. It is best practice to leave the question as-is, reward any acceptable answers (by up voting or selecting the answer), and then create a NEW question with any follow up issues that you are having. My answer below was to your original question; since you changed your question, the answer below now makes no sense. I would recommend that you change the question back to its original, and follow the best practice to create a new question so that you can get the help you need.

Comment: Hi , The original question was regarding creating keys and selecting user in order to see the pictures. I've followed your directions literally and created even 2 users but I could not see the pictures. Therefore I assume that maybe the  direction is not correct.  Also, in your direction you didn't mention about creation group for permission. Is it necessary? In another post it said that need to create group(link below).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949158/heroku-missing-required-arguments-aws-access-key-id-aws-secret-access-key-f

Answer (score 0):

From the IAM Console, click on "Users" in the left menu, and then "Create New Users". Enter a name for your new user and make sure the box "Generate an access key for each user" is checked. After you click "Create", you'll see "Show User Security Credentials". Click that and it'll expand to show you the `Access Key ID` and `Secret Access Key` for that user. Download the credentials now as you won't be able to access them again. That is what you'll use to set your Heroku ENV variables later on in the tutorial.

Now, go and create a new bucket in S3.

Back in IAM, you need to create a policy that you can attach to your new user that gives them access to that bucket. Click on "Policies" in the left menu, then "Create Policy", and then select "Create Your Own Policy". Copy and paste the first policy in [this blog post](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3VRSWZ6B3SHAV/Writing-IAM-Policies-How-to-grant-access-to-an-Amazon-S3-bucket) under "Policy for Programmatic Access". You'll have to change the resource name from `"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test"]` to `"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::<name_of_your_bucket"]`. Save the policy.

Now click on "Users" in the left menu, click on the new user that you just created, and go to the "Permissions" tab. Click "Attach Policy", search for the new policy that you just created, and click "Attach Policy".

Your new user should now have access to your new S3 bucket, and you can use the security credentials that you downloaded earlier to access the S3 bucket programmatically as that new user.

Comment: Policy Name
Description
Policy Document

Comment: Did this work for you? I was answering the question entitled: "How to create a user and record the keys?".

Comment: The purpose of the creating user and record the keys was the possibility to upload the picture in production. Yes, I create the user and the keys but maybe the creation was wrong and I need to use group(see my previous comment and link) with the users in order to upload the pictures? thanks.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to. You can either assign permissions to users directly, or put them in a group and assign permissions to the group.

Comment: For some reasons, I could not see the picture if i am not assigning to the group. Could you answer about how to ban the users and I mark you as the solver this question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is necessary to create User and Group from  IAM Console and attach the User to the Group in order to establish permissions. It is necessary to attach the policy to the group changing default values to your own values as below:

Policy Document:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": "s3:your value",

        "Effect": "Allow",

        "Resource": [

            "arn:aws:s3:::your value",

            "arn:aws:s3:::your value/*"

        ]
    }

]
```

}

After creating group and changing the policy regarding your own data, the pictures could be downloaded and become visible in the production.