# Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

While trying to run `rake db:create` for the first time, I keep getting the error `Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)`

Other people have posted this question and the response has been to look in the `carrierwave.rb` file, but my repository does not have this file. Inside of `fog.rb` I have:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'

    config.fog_credentials = {
       provider:              'AWS',                     # required
       region:                ENV["AWS_REGION"],               # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
       aws_access_key_id:     ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],  
       aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_KEY"] 

       #,host:                  's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
       #endpoint:              'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
       }
  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
   config.fog_directory  = 'policeboard-staging'                          # required
  end

  if Rails.env.production?
     config.fog_directory = 'policeboard-production'
  end

   config.fog_public     = true    # optional, defaults to true
   config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Here is the error log:

```
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:16:in `new'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:27:in `new'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-1dbc8be0bb8c/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:123:in `eager_load_fog'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-1dbc8be0bb8c/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:136:in `fog_credentials='
    from /Users/CharlieMerrill/code/policeboard/config/initializers/fog.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-1dbc8be0bb8c/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:158:in `configure'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-1dbc8be0bb8c/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
    from /Users/CharlieMerrill/code/policeboard/config/initializers/fog.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/CharlieMerrill/code/policeboard/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the error message you are seeing:

```
Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
```

It looks like you have not set those `ENV` variables: `ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]` and `ENV["AWS_SECRET_KEY"]`.

You can use [`figaro`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to help. Check out that repository and include it in you `Gemfile`. Then follow the installation instructions and it will help you set up your `ENV` variables in the `application.yml` file. Make sure you do not push these variables to a public repository.

You will also have to setup these `ENV` variables on whichever platform you are using to host.

Also check out this [comparable SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949158/heroku-missing-required-arguments-aws-access-key-id-aws-secret-access-key-f) for additional help.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation makes sense. Since I cloned this repository, do I need to get the original AWS keys from the creators?

Comment: If you need to contribute to this AWS account then yes. Otherwise if this is for practice or something like that then no. All depends on the context of this project.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing some work for this site, so I assume it needs to be on their AWS account. Thanks for your help!