# TypeError (no implicit conversion of Array into String) Rails App on Heroku Using AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hart's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page) and am stuck on Chapter 13. I am unable to post images on my Rails app deployed on Heroku, but images work just fine on the development server. My carrier_wave.rb originally looked like

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      # Configuration for Amazon S3
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region                => ENV['S3_REGION']
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

When my carrier_wave.rb looked like this I was getting an error that looked like this

```
:reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
```

After searching around on SO I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949158/heroku-missing-required-arguments-aws-access-key-id-aws-secret-access-key-f), and have changed my carrier_wave.rb to look like this

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp') # adding these...
  config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave' # ...two lines

  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :s3_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],                        # required
    :s3_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],                     # required
    :region                 => 'us-east-2',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    :host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    :endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_Bucket']                             # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Now I'm receiving the error

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Array into String)
```

I don't know if this is closer to working than the original carrier_wave.rb

My IAM user has 'AmazonS3FullAccess' as a permission. I have even tried setting the S3 Bucket to public access, but to no success. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: try changing this line `config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp').to_s`

Comment: Where's the stacktrace? It should tell you exactly what line is causing the problem.  I agree with @xploshioOn that it's likely your `config.root` line because it returns a `Pathname` object. But it may be that you need a proc. Check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2192) for more.